# Kendo Editor + AngularJS imageBrowser & fileBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

Can anyone tell me how i can add imageBrowser and fileBrowser to Kendo Editor using angular js?

currently using jQuery implementation is:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
    "insertImage",
    "insertFile"
    ],
    imageBrowser: {
        transport: {
            read: "foo",
            create: "foo",
            uploadUrl: "foo"
        }
    },
    fileBrowser: {
        transport: {
            read: "foo",
            create: "foo",
            uploadUrl: "foo"
        }
    }
});
```

I have implemented using AngularJS but i am not able to understand how i will add imageBrowser and File Browser to this control?

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <textarea kendo-editor
  k-tools="[
  'bold',
  'italic',
  'undeline',
  {
  name: 'foreColor',
  palette: [ '#f00', '#0f0', '#00f' ]
  }]">
</textarea>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you got the answer ? It will be great if you can share that. I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AnishV I have posted my solution below. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution which worked for me.

**Global Application BasePath**- In Layout.cshtml Head section

```
<script>
    var __appBasePath = 'http://localhost/myApp/';
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyEditorController">
    <textarea kendo-editor k-ng-model="Html" k-options="{{editorOptions}}" ></textarea>
</div>
```

**angularJS Controller - MyEditorController.js**

```
      $scope.editorOptions = {
        tools: [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull",
                "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                "indent",
                "outdent",
                "createLink",
                "unlink",
                "insertImage",
                "insertFile",
                "subscript",
                "superscript",
                "createTable",
                "addRowAbove",
                "addRowBelow",
                "addColumnLeft",
                "addColumnRight",
                "deleteRow",
                "deleteColumn",
                "viewHtml",
                "formatting",
                "cleanFormatting",
                "fontName",
                "fontSize",
                "foreColor",
                "backColor",
                "print"                    
        ],

        imageBrowser: {
            messages: {
                dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
            },

            transport: {
                type: "imagebrowser-aspnetmvc",
                read: __appBasePath + "ImageBrowser/Read",
                destroy: {
                    url: __appBasePath + "ImageBrowser/Destroy",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: __appBasePath + "ImageBrowser/Create",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                uploadUrl: __appBasePath + "ImageBrowser/upload",
                imageUrl: __appBasePath + "viewerImages/UserFiles/Images/{0}",
                thumbnailUrl: __appBasePath + "ImageBrowser/thumbnail"
            }
        },
        fileBrowser: {
            messages: {
                dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
            },

            transport: {
                type: "imagebrowser-aspnetmvc",
                read: __appBasePath + "FileBrowser/Read",
                destroy: {
                    url: __appBasePath + "FileBrowser/Destroy",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: __appBasePath + "FileBrowser/Create",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                uploadUrl: __appBasePath + "FileBrowser/upload",
                fileUrl: __appBasePath + "FileBrowser/File?path={0}"
            }
        }
    };
```

**ImageBrowserController.cs** - Controller which inherits KendoMVC EditorImageBrowserController

```
public class ImageBrowserController : EditorImageBrowserController
    {
        private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/MyImages/";

        private const string prettyName = "Images/";
        private static readonly string[] foldersToCopy = new[] { "~/MyImages/shared/" };


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the base paths from which content will be served.
        /// </summary>
        public override string ContentPath
        {
            get
            {
                return CreateUserFolder();
            }
        }

        private string CreateUserFolder()
        {
            var virtualPath = Path.Combine(contentFolderRoot, "UserFiles", prettyName);

            var path = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                foreach (var sourceFolder in foldersToCopy)
                {
                    CopyFolder(Server.MapPath(sourceFolder), path);
                }
            }
            return virtualPath;
        }

        private void CopyFolder(string source, string destination)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
            }

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(file));
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, dest);
            }

            foreach (var folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(folder));
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            }
        }  
    }
```

**FileBrowserController.cs** - controller which inherits KendoMVC EditorFileBrowserController

```
   public class FileBrowserController : EditorFileBrowserController
    {
        private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/viewerImages/";
        private const string prettyName = "Images/";
        private static readonly string[] foldersToCopy = new[] { "~/viewerImages/shared/" };


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the base paths from which content will be served.
        /// </summary>
        public override string ContentPath
        {
            get
            {
                return CreateUserFolder();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the valid file extensions by which served files will be filtered.
        /// </summary>
        public override string Filter
        {
            get
            {
                return "*.txt, *.doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.pdf, *.zip, *.rar, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png";
            }
        }

        private string CreateUserFolder()
        {
            var virtualPath = Path.Combine(contentFolderRoot, "UserFiles", prettyName);

            var path = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                foreach (var sourceFolder in foldersToCopy)
                {
                    CopyFolder(Server.MapPath(sourceFolder), path);
                }
            }
            return virtualPath;
        }

        private void CopyFolder(string source, string destination)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
            }

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(file));
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, dest);
            }

            foreach (var folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(folder));
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How did you get the value for variable __appBasePath ?

Comment: __appBasePath is just a global javascript variable which hold application base path of application

Comment: One challenge is that, I'm using a Web API project instead of MVC. How to do this in web api controller ? Any idea ? I have referenced the Kendo MVC dll anyway.

Comment: in transport use your web api controllers to read and write i.e. read: __appBasePath + "/api/ImageBrowser/Read",

Comment: Is it possible to use EditorFileBrowserController in api controller ?